# thread does not working for exit from form2

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

thread does not working for exit from form2

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadStart myThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(RunExitForm2);
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    Thread MyThread = new Thread(myThreadDelegate);
    f2.ShowDialog();
    MyThread.Start();

}
private void RunExitForm2()
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

You are probably better off putting a `Timer` on Form2 that will close the window 2 seconds after it opens.  The icon on the toolbox looks like a stopwatch.  In the properties window, set `Interval=2000` and `Enabled=True`, then subscribe to the `Tick` event and say `this.Close();`

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
   this.Close ();
}
```

Original answer:

For starters, you usually can't muck with system.windows.forms stuff with worker threads.  You need to use the UI "message loop" thread.

The other problem is that the Thread isn't started until you close the first window (because of the `.ShowDialog()`.  The worker thread news up a form (but never shows it), then closes it (but it's not open), so it would never appear anyway.

Comment: By "message loop" thread, I mean main thread that application runs on.  The thread that that the window is shown on.

Comment: How do I create "message loop"

Comment: @jack, you don't need to create it because (it's probably in your Program.cs).  Look for `Application.Run (new Form1 ());`  That creates it.  Anyway, here's a new answer in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Is this like you mean ?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frmTest = new Form2();

        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(f =>
        {
            // easy to see the effect...
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Form2 me = f as Form2;
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                me.Close();
            }));

        }, frmTest);

        frmTest.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: i dont think its a good idea for worker threads to do any GUI stuff directly, like the closing of forms

Comment: I think If have tried to create a splash screen at first for serval seconds...  you'd like to control the wait time at outside....and also close it at the same place....:)

Comment: you can still do that, just use a Timer() component on either the main or splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the code you are creating two instances of Form2, while trying to close you create a new instance.

One more point, even if you have only one instance, you are creating a form on main thread and trying to close it on different worker thread, you will get cross thread exception.

Let me know whats exactly is your requirement. As mentioned earlier in this post, its not a good idea to allow worker threads to access UI elements

This is what i would do

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadStart myThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(RunExitForm2);

```
        Thread MyThread = new Thread(myThreadDelegate);
        MyThread.Start();
        f2.ShowDialog(Application.OpenForms[0]);



    }

    private void RunExitForm2()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

       test t = new test(f2.CloseForm2);


        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke( t);
            return;
        }

    }
```

Here test is delegate to method to Closeform2 defined in Form2, in which i just close the form

Answer (score 0):

You should never call a Method or Property of a UI Control from a second thread.

Have a look at [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)